# Script to split JS comma-separated var declaration into multiple var declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large codebase with a ton of stuff declared like this:

```
var x = 1,
y = {
     //some object
},
z = function(arg) {
    // some function
};
```

I'd like to run a node script to convert all this to

```
var x = 1;
var y = {
   //some object
};
var z = function(arg) {
   // some function
};
```

It's not as simple as running a regex on it, because as soon as an object or function appears, you can't just look for commas and semicolons anymore.

Is there an existing library or tool which can do this conversion for me? Not looking to minify or uglify the code, I'm just looking to modify existing, human-readable code to get rid of the comma-separated var declarations.

Comment: That doesn't work when there are curly braces inside curly braces. I could write a parser for that, but I don't want to do that if there's already an open source solution for all of this including edge cases.

Comment: Requests for a 3rd party library or tool are considered off-topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Are there situations where the character sequence `,` followed by an `identifier` and then a single `=` can exist outside of a multiple var declaration? I'm having trouble thinking of one outside of a string literal with those characters, because a single `=` is used for assignment, and I'm not sure why you'd have a comma before an assignment statement except in the initialization form you're trying to replace.

Granted, it's always risky to use regex in situations where a parser is more appropriate. The pattern would look something like:

`,\s*([\$a-z_][\$a-z_0-9]*)(?=\s*=[^=])`

Note: The Visual Studio plugin Resharper has a refactoring for this very operation.  However, unlike many other refactorings, Resharper does not provide the option to apply this globally.

Comment: Ah I have found at least one other place that would fail, and that's a multivariate for loop: `for(var x=0, y=1; ...)`

Comment: No need to escape `$` in character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if all your comma separators lie at the end of a line, you could just use the regex:

```
replace(/,\n/g, ';\nvar ');
```

Here's a browser example:

```js
// in node, this would come straight from a file
var string = 'var x = 1,\ny = {\n  //some object \n},\nz = function(arg) {\n  // some function\n};';

// heres an element we can use for results
var code = document.getElementById('code');

// lets show original string
code.innerHTML = string;

// lets show the new string in a couple of seconds
setTimeout( function () {
  
  // the regex replace
  var updated = string.replace(/,\n/g, ';\nvar ');

  // updating the code element
  code.innerHTML = updated;
  
  // change color to signify finished
  code.className = 'done';
  
}, 2000);
```

```css
code {
  
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}

.done {
  
  background-color: #C0D9AF;  
  
}
```

```html
<code id="code"></code>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

jsfmt --rewrite "a=b,c=d -> var a=b; var c=d;" input.js > output.js

input.js:

```
var x = 1,
y = {
     //some object
},
z = function(arg) {
    // some function
};
```

output.js:

```
var x = 1;
var y = {
    //some object
  };
var z = function(arg) {
    // some function
  };
```

using [jsfmt](https://github.com/rdio/jsfmt)